# Collection not rendered on time even though I'm using waitOn?

Tags: meteor

This is the code:

```
Meteor.publish('singleDocument', function(documentId) {
  return Documents.find(documentId);
});

this.route("documentPage", {
  path: "/documents/:_id",
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe("singleDocument", this.params._id);
  },
  data: function() {
    return Documents.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});

Template.documentPage.rendered = function() {
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
       console.log(this.content);
    });
};
```

As you can see I have everything set and I'm waiting on the collection with `waitOn`. But `console.log(this.content);` still returning `undefined` as if the collection hasn't loaded yet.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the autorun does not refer to the data context used to render the template. In the rendered function, outside the autorun function (you shouldn't need to use autorun at all), you can use `this.data` to refer to the data context used to render the template, so try the following:

```js
Template.documentPage.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.data);
};
```

**Update according to comment below:**

You should be able to use [Template.currentData](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata) to listen for changes in the data context:

```js
Template.documentPage.rendered = function() {
    Tracker.autorun(function(){
        console.log(Template.currentData())
    })
};
```

Comment: You're right it worked. Thanks. So there's no way of using it inside Tracker.autorun? In case I want to use it in a function that I want to run each time the collection updates?

Comment: @alexchenco, I think you can use Template.currentData. See my updated answer.